# Display multiple sensor data from serial port with javascript and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, charts, socket.io, arduino

i am new to Node.JS and Arduino. I have an Arduino setup  with a temperature sensors on it. I am reading temperature values with Arduino. My serial monitor output like this:

> serial Monitor:

```
0.05
0.10
0.15
0.20
0.25
0.30
0.34
```

I send data from a Arduino to my terminal with serialport then displayed data on my webbrowser in chart form. I'm using the express and socket.io.
here is the connection with the arduino and browser with index.js. And a index.html

> index.js:

```
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var server = http.listen(4000, "0.0.0.0", () => { //Start the server, listening on port 4000.
        console.log("Listening to requests on port 4000...");
    })

    var io = require('socket.io')(server); //Bind socket.io to our express server.

    app.use(express.static('public')); //Send index.html page on GET /

    const SerialPort = require('serialport');
    const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
    const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0'); //Connect serial port to port COM3. Because my Arduino Board is connected on port COM3. See yours on Arduino IDE -> Tools -> Port
    const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({delimiter: '\r\n'})); //Read the line only when new line comes.
    parser.on('data', (temp) => { //Read data
        console.log(temp);
        var today = new Date();
        io.sockets.emit('temp', {date: today.getDate()+"-"+today.getMonth()+1+"-"+today.getFullYear(), time: (today.getHours())+":"+(today.getMinutes()), temp:temp}); //emit the datd i.e. {date, time, temp} to all the connected clients.
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log("Someone connected."); //show a log as a new client connects.
    })
```

The temperature data is recieved from the serialport Arduino is displayed in the index.html (webbrowser).

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Temperature Plot</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Temperature Graph</h1>
        <h4>Date: <span id="date"></span></h4>
        <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:75vw; margin: auto;">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:4000'); //connect to server
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',
                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Temperature",
                    borderColor: "#FF5733",
                    data: [],
                    fill: false,
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    backgroundColor: '#3498DB',
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverRadius: 7,
                    lineTension: 0,
                }]
                },
                // Configuration options go here
                options: {}

            });
            socket.on('temp', function(data) { //As a temp data is received
                console.log(data.temp);
                document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data.date; //update the date
                if(chart.data.labels.length != 15) { //If we have less than 15 data points in the graph
                    chart.data.labels.push(data.time);  //Add time in x-asix
                    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                        dataset.data.push(data.temp); //Add temp in y-axis
                    });
                }
                else { //If there are already 15 data points in the graph.
                    chart.data.labels.shift(); //Remove first time data
                    chart.data.labels.push(data.time); //Insert latest time data
                    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                        dataset.data.shift(); //Remove first temp data
                        dataset.data.push(data.temp); //Insert latest temp data
                    });
                }
                chart.update(); //Update the graph.
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }
        h4 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }
        p {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

everything works fine if there is only 1 sensor temperature on Arduino, but when I add another temperature sensor with the serial monitor results as below, make sensors data unable to appear in the form of chart in index.html, and the console browser also only displays the same data as the serial monitor.

> serial monitor with 2 temperature sensor (the results of reading between temperature sensors with each other are separated by spaces)

```
0.05 1.00
0.10 1.00
0.15 0.99
0.20 0.98
0.25 0.97
0.30 0.96
0.34 0.94
```

I have tried to solve this problem for almost a week, I have tried many ways to solve this problem but it didn't work, I do need your help

> arduino code:

```
double x; //I simulate 2 temperature sensor values
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      x = 0;
    }

    void loop() {  
      Serial.print(sin(x));
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.println(cos(x));
      delay(50);

      // seting batasan input fungsi sinus
      x += 0.05;
      if(x>= 2*3.14){
        x = 0;
      }  
    }
```

Comment: The format of output by the serial port will depend on your arduino code. What you can do is prefix "Sensor 1 :" like string to the sensor data and then parse the output based on this .

Comment: For better help, please post your arduino code.

Comment: @ZeekHuge, 
I have updated my question by adding the arduino code

Comment: So you mean 'sin(×)' is sensor1-data and 'cos(x)' is sensor 2 data ?

Comment: yes right @ZeekHuge

Comment: i already try using prefix to print string "Sensor 1:" in Arduino IDE, following the sensor 1 data which is 'sin(x)' but it still didnt work @ZeekHuge

Comment: What is your expected result ? Do you want a different graph of the second-sensor-data ? Or what ?

Comment: yes i want different graph for second sensor data, can you give me example of real working code to show second data, My code still fails to display the second data

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 questions in it.

1. How to format the data and use the `express` server and send it to the front-end
2. How to display more than one data-set in in the graph using chart.js

### **For 1st**

The line in your code

```
...
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({delimiter: '\r\n'}));
...
```

Actually captures each line of data. But since your output from arduino contains data in the same line, we will have to `split()` it at the `space` character. So to get an `array` of more than one temperature values, you can use `tempArray = temp.split(" ");`. This array then can be sent to the front-end.

### For 2nd

After you have the array of the temperature values, you can send that array itself to the front end using

```
// Notice I have replaced `temp` with `tempArray`
io.sockets.emit('temp', {date:today.getDate()+"-"+today.getMonth()+1+"-"+today.getFullYear(), time: (today.getHours())+":"+(today.getMinutes()), temp:tempArray}); });
```

In the front-end, the `dataset` in the `Chart` object is an array. And if you want to add more than one datasets to the chart, you can add them simply by adding one more dataset object :

```
....
datasets: [{
           label: "Sensor1",
           borderColor: "#FF5733",
           data: [],
           fill: false,
           pointStyle: 'circle',
           backgroundColor: '#3498DB',
           pointRadius: 5,
           pointHoverRadius: 7,
           lineTension: 0,
          },
....
....

          {
           label: "Sensor2",
           borderColor: "#FFFF33",
           data: [],
           fill: false,
           pointStyle: 'circle',
           backgroundColor: '#34FFDB',
           pointRadius: 5,
           pointHoverRadius: 7,
           lineTension: 0,
          },
]
....
```

Now, inside the `socket.on('temp', function(data){...})` you can push data like this :

`chart.dataset[i].data.push(data.temp[i]) // looping over i`

### **Edit**

To put in the data into the datasets, you can use a 'for' loop as follows :

```
for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
    chart.datasets[i].data.push(data.temp[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Amirullah Achmad Nassardhi : Is this answer not correct ?

Comment: I have tried the code for hours, and the problem I still face is how I connect and specify between datasets with temp[] values. for example how I connect datasets labeled sensor1 with temp​​[0] , and how I connect dataset labeled sensor2 with temp[1]

Comment: Edited the answer and added a for loop.

Comment: I'm still confused with laying for loop. can you give an example of the code that works on 'socket.on('temp', function(data) { });'  
because the data displayed in the code can only display data from sensor1, what about the data from sensor 2?

Comment: You understand that in your `index.html`, the `chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {...})` line is a loop over the elements in the `datasets` field. right ? Just replace that loop with the above given loop.